# Не правильно работает условие

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, re

Юзеру приходится вводить номер два раза чтобы получить некст сообщение от бота.

TestDate, [15.06.2023 18:35]
Напиши, пожалуйста, свой номер телефона по формату +7----------

[15.06.2023 18:35]
+77777777

[15.06.2023 18:35]
+77777777

TestDate, [15.06.2023 18:35]
Напиши, пожалуйста, email (важно, т.к. электронный адрес должен совпадать с тем, что ты укажешь при оплате

Вот код

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.phone_number)
async def process_surname(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    phone_number = message.text
    phone_number_pattern = r'^\+7\d{10}$'
    if not re.match(phone_number_pattern, phone_number):
        await message.answer("Напиши, пожалуйста, свой номер телефона по формату +7----------")
    else:
        await Form.next()
```

Вроде такого не должно быть